# Why I can't open the kernel git repo in my GIT GUI client?

Tags: git, cloning

I successfully cloned the kernel using git in command line, nevertheless I find difficult to navigate throughout the repo using the cli and I got a gui client, gitkraken to be specific.

The thing here is that **I can't open the repo using the gitkraken and I don't know why**, specially because I have another git repo that works just fine with the gui client.

Has somebody experienced this? What could be wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: What does "can't open the repo" mean? What error message do you get, or what happens? What is the URI you're cloning from?

Comment: @ChrisDown I'm cloning from git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git and the error message is: "Could not find a compatible repository" and I'm getting that when I simply try the "File>Open" in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Gitkraken doesn't like the `<...>.git` in the directory path.

Make a symbolic link without a dot and open the repository via that path!

```
ln -s <path>linux.git linux_git
```